# Saving User Generated Form Created Queries

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm programming a LAMP stack online application that uses a very complex search form, I want to give the user the ability to name and save their current search for faster use in the future (they will be checking these results daily). What is the best methodology to do this? I've been coming across stored procedures, but this doesn't seem like what I'm looking for.

My current idea:

Pull php generated query into dedicated database for saving queries (all form input data is sanitized / validated). Is this a security risk? I know all form generated SQL is a risk of course. When the user wants to query with it, the PHP code will simply use the saved query over the form generated one. If I change the form generated query code in the future, this should prevent conflicts, but of course, it won't take advantage of any new design features.

Comment: Rather than trying to save the whole query, maybe try to save the parameters in the database? Then use those parameters to construct the query when you need to retrieve the information.

Comment: Saving the parameters would also allow you to build parameterized query rather than running a static query when you wanna retrieve the information.

Comment: One downside of this approach would be a more complex database structure to store the information.

Comment: Yes, I did consider storing all the separate variables, but this also has it's own issues if the database changes (maybe I dump a column or change it in some way).

Comment: That would still be better than the case when the form itself changes. As mentioned in the answer below, in that case the queries would become obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't imagine this is "best practice" (or that there is one, in this case). Personally I think I'd rather store their search terms in a format devoid of context (say in a JSON-encoded object if there are multiple search terms or conditions), and then when they recall the search rebuild the queries from the JSON object.

(Storing the actual query seems to run the risk of old queries becoming obsolete if/when the underlying database structure changes. Storing only what they're searching for and rebuilding it allows you to accommodate for that.)

My $0.02.

---

To answer your question, yes. Regardless of how you store it, you would store the values they entered in whatever your form collects, then when they rerun the stored "search" you would go through that structure and remake your query.

The table might have `search_id`, `user_id`, `search_name`, `parameters` and whatever else. They pull up a list of their saved searches, choose one, execute it, you pull `parameters`, rebuild the query, run it, and display the results, just as you would when they did the original search through the normal form.

Comment: JSON, as in a JSON stored inside a database table? I think I understand what you're saying, basically create an array that is utilized to rebuild the query?

Comment: Yes, that's it. See my edit above.